# jQuery tabs with both Ajax and static div's

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, html, tabs

I am posting form data to a page that is using jQuery tabs.  Because you can't load post data into an Ajax query (at least without a ton of extra work and making it more insecure), I'm loading the active tab as an actual div on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tabs').tabs({ selected: 3 });
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs" style="margin-top: 10px">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="myprofile.php">My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="mycompany.php">My Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="manageusers.php">Manage Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#manageallusers">Manage All Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="manageclients.php">Manage Clients</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="manageallusers"></div>
</div>
```

In the example above, all tabs except the "Manage All Users" tab is called via the Ajax method in the jQuery tabs function.  The other is just a static div already on the page.  On initial load, this works beautifully.  However, if you begin to click through the Ajax tabs, the static div remains beneath.

There is a 'load:' callback in the tabs() function.  I know I should be using this -- I'm just not sure at all how to approach it.  Any thoughts, suggestions??

Comment: So what are you trying to do? The static div is NOT going to move - It's static.

Comment: This should work fine.  jQuery UI tabs should auto-hide and show the static tab.  There's no real difference between working with AJAX tabs and regular "div" tabs.

Comment: why is doing an xhr post more insecure than a normal form post?

Comment: @redsquare: Ajax post is more insecure in this scenario because the data has already been posted to the page and I'm displaying it again with either an error or confirmation.  If I was reposting it back again with Ajax, all the post data would need to be written out in the JS.

@cdmckay: That's what I thought, but the div doesn't hide :(

Comment: @Nathan Loding: That's very strange, because I've been using jQuery UI Tabs extensively in my current project and have not had to do any manual hiding.  The only possibility I can think of is that you're applying some extra CSS to the static div that is causing it not to be hidden (or somehow overriding jQuery UIs hiding mechanism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#tabs").tabs(
        {
            load: function(ui)
            {
                $("#manageallusers").hide();
            }
        });
```

This is what you would use if you were trying to hide it. You could obviously swap it out with whatever you want to do, because you weren't very specific about it.

Comment: @Sneakyness: This is what I was looking for.  I guess I was just way over-thinking it.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's different to say the least. I'm using the same thing to get some magic done on www.sneakyness.com

Comment: Ha!  I also found a typo that was throwing an exception during certain conditions that was partially attributing to this.  Still had to use this method though: load: function(event, ui) { if(this.href == '#manageallusers') { $('#manageallusers').show(); } else { $('#manageallusers').hide(); } }